# SSIS error column data type is not supported by pipelinebuffer class

Tags: ssis, pipeline

I am running a SSIS job in debug mode and keep getting the below error message. this was caused when I changed the column data type from date to datetime

```
Column data type DT_UI1 is not supported by the PipelineBuffer class.
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.PipelineBuffer.GetString(Int32 columnIndex)
   at ScriptComponent_0cc90dbe638944239c3c93b75a4350fa.vbproj.InputBuffer.get_matchedoriginatingsystemname()
   at ScriptComponent_0cc90dbe638944239c3c93b75a4350fa.vbproj.ScriptMain.Input_ProcessInputRow(InputBuffer Row)
   at ScriptComponent_0cc90dbe638944239c3c93b75a4350fa.vbproj.UserComponent.Input_ProcessInput(InputBuffer Buffer)
   at ScriptComponent_0cc90dbe638944239c3c93b75a4350fa.vbproj.UserComponent.ProcessInput(Int32 InputID, PipelineBuffer Buffer)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ScriptComponentHost.ProcessInput(Int32 inputID, PipelineBuffer buffer)
```

Comment: *How* did you change the column data type from date to datetime? DT_UI1 is an unsigned, one-byte integer

Comment: I just clicked one the column output ans changed it to datetime from date

Comment: @Abbaskhan6428 you should provide more info. What are the components, transformations you are using?